# How to render postprocessed light object and THEN object from another layer that covers it? Preferably eevee solution

Tags: eevee-render-engine, compositing-nodes, layers

Hey i started learning blender this week and i set my first non cube project to be lightsaber.
I had some problems with postprocessing glow effect but i found solution involving  two layers first with just glowing blade and another layer with rest of the scene objects. Result is nice but when i move the camera so that lightsaber hilt is between my mesh start to look translucent and those purple faces appear because well i set it up that way i think.

[image]
[image]

Here is my composition:
[image]

Answer (score 1):

I dont know why but suddenly it works
[image]

Seems to worked after i set up cryptomatte like for cycles even though it doesnt work with eevee so yeah, like this:
[image]

I guess glare threshold is working like this so maybe i changed lightning and it didnt affect the rest or? Well anyway its solved now.